# Is there any way to skip number request in telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

Every time if my session is invalid i got this output: "Please enter your phone (or bot token): "
Is there anyway to pass it or ignore it?

I tried to edit telethon source code, but im bad at it))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for everyone who have the same problem

```
client = TelegramClient(f"session", api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
print(client)
if client.is_user_authorized():
  print("VALID")
else:
  print('NO VALID')
```

Everything was much easier, than i thought

Answer (score -2):

Telethon project implements Telegram API and there is no way to skip it since it's required by protocol.

As an option I can advice you to check if [authenticating as a bot](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/signing-in.html#signing-in-as-a-bot-account) instead of a normal user can solve your problem depending on your task.